# Pourquoi un verbe transitif/intransitif est-il appelé comme ça; quel est l'étymologie des mots transitif and intransitif?

Tags: verbes, étymologie, origine-ou-raison, linguistique, transitivité

Je ne sais pas si il s'agit du bon endroit où poser cette question, mais aucune autre source ne semble avoir de réponse.

Quel est l'étymologie du mot transitif and intransitif? Pour moi, ça me rappelle a "transition" mais je ne vois pas le rapport avec la fonction d'un verbe transitif.

Et selon l'étymologie du mot, pourquoi est-ce qu'un verbe transitif est appelé comme ça? Je cherche à comprendre en fait pourquoi ce mot en particulier a était sélectionné pour définir ce type de verbe, et quel rapport entre son appellation et sa fonction.

Et si, par hasard, vous auriez un livre a recommandé qui explique l'origine des termes de linguistiques, je suis preneuse. Car chercher en ligne n'apporte pas forcément de réponses.

Comment: Vous devriez d'abord consulter des dictionnaires, lorsque c'est possible, et c'est possible dans le cas présent. Un très bon dictionnaire, le TLFi, vous donnera souvent la réponse que vous cherchez. Pour votre question voyez d'abord  [TLFI, transitif](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/transitif). Si cela n'est pas suffisant, modifiez votre question pour expliquer ce que vous ne comprenez pas dans le dictionnaire.

Comment: Notez que dans le TLFi vous avez une étymologie à la fin de l'entrée.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TRANSITIF, IVE adj. est emprunté (v. 1265) au latin *transitivus*
> employé par les grammairiens latins à propos d'un verbe qui fait
> passer l'action du sujet sur son complément direct. Le mot vient de
> *transire* « passer » (→ transir).
>
> ❏ *Transitif* a d'abord été emprunté au sens général de « passager,
> changeant », sorti d'usage à la fin du XV<sup>e</sup> s., puis a été repris par
> les grammairiens (1550, Meigret, *Traité de la grammaire française*)
> au sens latin, appliqué aussi (1625) à ce qui est propre à un verbe
> transitif. Le mot, donné comme terme de grammaire hébraïque par
> l'*Encyclopédie*, est très rare avant le XIX<sup>e</sup> s. ; on disait plutôt
> *verbe actif*. [...]
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, chez
> Robert, 2011 ]

---

> [image]
>
> Nous appelons un verbe transitif, quand son action se peut transférer
> en un autre: comme, j'endors Pierre, qui est autant à dire, que je
> fais dormir Pierre: par ce moyen je suis la cause qui fait que
> l'action de dormir, s'imprime en Pierre.
>
> [ [*Le tretté de la grammere françoeze*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4530t/f117.item.r=grammaire%20grammaire), Louis Meigret (1550), p.
> 85. ]

Voir aussi au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/transitif) ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intransitif)) et sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivit%C3%A9_(grammaire)) (« Il s'agit d'un terme de grammaire qui qualifie des verbes exprimant une action qui, du sujet, est transmise directement au complément ; en d'autres termes ce sont des verbes qui ont un caractère de transition entre un sujet et un objet »). Généralement, on peut sans doute les distinguer des verbes [attributifs](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24285/la-grammaire/la-grammaire-actuelle/les-fonctions/lattribut) et intransitifs, qui, différemment, n'ont pas ce caractère ; ou l'emploi transitif d'un verbe de son emploi intransitif le cas échéant.